# Division returns NaN in browser Number in console

Tags: javascript, logic, logical-operators

```
let cat1 = 0
    let Catego1 = 0

cat1 = (cat1 * 100) / Catego1

<td>{Math.floor(cat1)} %</td>
```

in this bit of code i get a NaN % in the browser and 0 with type Number if i typeof it, by now i pinpointed that as soon as i divide the (cat1 * 100) with a 0 this happens and js is very tricky about types.
NOTE: i happened to have the same exact code in other pages(forced to duplicate) and this only happens in one of the 5 pages.

so far i have tried ParseInt , Parsefloat, Number, used math libraries but i got nowhere near solving it
thank you!

Comment: You're dividing by 0. (`let Catego1 = 0`)

Comment: 0/0 is undefined

Comment: actually it's NaN

Comment: Why are you dividing by zero and what do you expect from it? The percentage out of zero items total is a meaningless operation. The closest "sensible" values would be zero (nothing out of nothing), or 100% (everything out of nothing). But even then, the whole trying to get the percentage *out of nothing* is not very sensible to begin with. So, I'd focus on what should be happening instead of this.

Comment: if the condidate answers wrong to all the questions then the percentage should be 0 according to the equation of scoring, ain't that logical?

Comment: @EagleMind If they answer wrong to all questions, then you should be calculating `0 / number_of_questions` which is indeed zero. If there are 10 questions and somebody answers correct 2 of them, that's 2 / 10 = 20%. You shouldn't be dividing by 2 in order to derive the percentage.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are dividing 0 with 0 which is undefined.(NaN)

Comment: if i take your words for granted then it means its impossible to return 0 as integer in the browser, which is not logical, ps: console.log shows 0 typeof number

Comment: You can return 0. That's not the issue. 
You can't divide by 0. It's not a browser thing, it's a math thing. How do you divide a group of things into 0 groups? You can't.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish, but it ***is*** clear that you're confused by the "type Number".

The value NaN, despite its literally meaning "Not a Number", as actually a value that can be taken by the Number type in JavaScript. JavaScript at its core has only a few "types". Unlike C++ where you have int, float, long, etc -- JavaScript just has:

- Undefined
- Number
- String
- Object
- Array
- Function

Everything else is just a combination of these.

When you perform a mathematical operation on two "Number" types the output is always a "Number", with some value. For instance: `var x = 2 / 4;` will set `typeof x === "number"` and `x === 0.5`.

In your case you performed a mathematical operation (division) on two "Number" types (zero and zero) so the output must be a Number:

```
var x = 0 / 0;
console.log(typeof x); // "number"
```

But what's the ***value*** of that number? Division by zero isn't possible, so you get back "Not a Number" -- because its value is something nonsensical.

If you're seeing a value of "0" anywhere for this, it's because you have some library or function that's transforming your output to a string and, not understanding `NaN`, is returning "0" (possibly a bug in whatever templating system you're using). Consider something like the following:

```
console.log(x > 0 ? x : 0);
```

This code ***seems*** like it's clamping the output value to positive numbers. If `x` is greater than 0, we output it. If it's not (it's less than zero) then we output 0. But what if `x` is `NaN`? In JavaScript all comparisons (other than "not equal") using the value of `NaN` will always return false:

```
x > 0; // false
x < 0; // false
x === 0; // false
x !== 0; // true
```

So we end up outputting 0 for `NaN`!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xzJcyQGX

even harcoding it like this didn't work :
Math.floor(cat1) == 0 ? "0": Math.floor(cat1)

but as you well explained there is not way out of it besides finding what's corrupting the output am i right based on the pastebin!?

Comment: @EagleMind Seeing your code now on pastebin, I can see both the cause of your issue and what you're trying to accomplish. You have some category for which there are no questions or answers - meaning `CategoX` is 0 (hence the division by 0). In your output code you should either use `isNaN()` to check for `NaN` explicitly after division, or you should say something like `Catego1 === 0 ? "N/A" : cat1` - this explicitly checks for the **cause** of the `NaN` value, and allows you to give customized output explaining why a real value isn't possible